# Playlist in Windows 8 app

Tags: c#, windows, windows-8

I'm trying to make a playlist in Windows 8. I can create a playlist but MediElement doesn't want to play the playlist. My question is: How can I play `.wpl` file in Windows 8 using C#? Here is my code:

```
  async private void PickAudioButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        FileOpenPicker picker = MainPage.CreateFilePicker(MainPage.audioExtensions);
        IReadOnlyList<StorageFile> files = await picker.PickMultipleFilesAsync();

         MainPage.playlist = new Playlist();

            foreach (StorageFile file in files)
            {
                MainPage.playlist.Files.Add(file);
            }

            StorageFile savedFile = await MainPage.playlist.SaveAsAsync(KnownFolders.MusicLibrary,
                                                                        "Sample",
                                                                        NameCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting,
                                                                        PlaylistFormat.WindowsMedia);

            xcv.SetSource((await savedFile.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.Read)), ".wpl");
            xcv.Play();
            MainPage.playlist = null;
       }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATE 1**

You can load WPL, ZPL or M3U playlist through `Playlist` class. Check the below given code.

```
var filepicker = new FileOpenPicker();
filepicker.SuggestedStartLocation = PickerLocationId.MusicLibrary;
filepicker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".wpl");
filepicker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".zpl");
filepicker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".m3u");
var file = await filepicker.PickSingleFileAsync();

if (file != null)
{
    var playlist = await Playlist.LoadAsync(file); 
    var allMediaFiles = playlist.Files;
}
```

---

In WinRT, `MediaElement` does not support playing WPL playlist directly. WPL file is basically XML file, it contains path of all the media files which are part of WPL playlist. So you can deserialize that file and create list of `StorageFile` and then media files with `MediaElement`. Use `MediaEnded` event to set the `MediaElement`'s `Source` to the next media in your list.

[Supported audio and video formats (Windows Store apps)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh986969.aspx)

[Serializing Objects in your WinRT Applications using XmlDeSerializer](http://www.kunal-chowdhury.com/2012/11/win8dev-tutorial-windows-store-winrt-xml-serialization.html)

**Hint** : To get XML serializable class from XML, copy XML by opening WPL file in text editor i.e. notepad. Create new class file in Visual Studio 2012. Go to Edit menu then Paste Special & then Paste XML as Classes. You will get ready made classes.